# Why does casting a variable in a class's instance cast it in another instance of the parent class as well?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, opengl

I've been trying to get a little 3D engine ready to work, but I've ran into a few issues. Namely:
When I try to add an animation to one of my objects/classes, it's geometry (a variable used to describe it's shape) overwrites some other objects from it's parent class as well.

I'll insert a few code snipplets here to show what I mean:
**Geometry parent class:**

```
class ParamSurface : public Geometry {
    //---------------------------
    unsigned int nVtxPerStrip, nStrips;
public:
    ParamSurface() { nVtxPerStrip = nStrips = 0; }

    virtual VertexData GenVertexData(float u, float v) = 0;

    void create(int N = tessellationLevel, int M = tessellationLevel) {
        nVtxPerStrip = (M + 1) * 2;
        nStrips = N;
        std::vector<VertexData> vtxData;    // vertices on the CPU
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= M; j++) {
                vtxData.push_back(GenVertexData((float)j / M, (float)i / N));
                vtxData.push_back(GenVertexData((float)j / M, (float)(i + 1) / N));
            }
        }
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nVtxPerStrip * nStrips * sizeof(VertexData), &vtxData[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        // Enable the vertex attribute arrays
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // attribute array 0 = POSITION
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);  // attribute array 1 = NORMAL
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);  // attribute array 2 = TEXCOORD0
        // attribute array, components/attribute, component type, normalize?, stride, offset
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (void*)offsetof(VertexData, position));
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (void*)offsetof(VertexData, normal));
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData), (void*)offsetof(VertexData, texcoord));
    }

    void Draw() {
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nStrips; i++) glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, i * nVtxPerStrip, nVtxPerStrip);
    }
};
```

**Geometry derived class(es):**

```
class Sphere2 : public ParamSurface{
public:
    float R = 1.0f;
    float Rt = 1.0f;

    Sphere2(float f = 1.0f) { R = f; create(); }

    float F(float u, float v, long t) {
        float n = 2.0f;
        return 1.0 + (R * cosf(n * u) * sinf(n * v) * sinf(t)) * 0.5;
    }

    VertexData GenVertexData(float u, float v) {
        VertexData vd;
        float t = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 200;
        float U = u * 2.0f * (float)M_PI;
        float V = v * (float)M_PI;
        Rt = F(U, V, t);
        vd.position = vd.normal = vec3( Rt * R * cosf(U) * sinf(V), Rt * R * sinf(U) * sinf(V), Rt * R * cosf(V));
        vd.texcoord = vec2(u, v);
        return vd;
    }
};
```

*(this one changes it's shape based on time, so it's kind of animated, however it has to be re-created every time from scratch)*

```
class Tractricoid : public ParamSurface {
    float height = 3;
public:
    Tractricoid(float f1 = 3.0f) { height = f1; create(); }

    VertexData GenVertexData(float u, float v) {
        VertexData vd;
        float U = u * height;
        float V = v * 2.0f * (float)M_PI;
        vd.position = vd.normal = vec3(
            cosf(V) / coshf(U),
            sinf(V) / coshf(U),
            U - tanhf(U));
        vd.texcoord = vec2(u, v);
        return vd;
    }
};
```

*(This is a non-animated (fix) shape that should look like one half of those items used in the Inception movie used to decide wether someone is sleeping or not)*

**The Object parent class that uses these Geometries:**

```
struct Object {
    //---------------------------
    Shader* shader;
    Material* material;
    Texture* texture;
    Geometry* geometry;
    vec3 scale, translation, rotationAxis;
    float rotationAngle;
public:
    Object(Shader* _shader, Material* _material, Texture* _texture, Geometry* _geometry) :
        scale(vec3(1, 1, 1)), translation(vec3(0, 0, 0)), rotationAxis(0, 0, 1), rotationAngle(0) {
        shader = _shader;
        texture = _texture;
        material = _material;
        geometry = _geometry;
    }
    virtual void SetModelingTransform(mat4& M, mat4& Minv) {
        M = ScaleMatrix(scale) * RotationMatrix(rotationAngle, rotationAxis) * TranslateMatrix(translation);
        Minv = TranslateMatrix(-translation) * RotationMatrix(-rotationAngle, rotationAxis) * ScaleMatrix(vec3(1 / scale.x, 1 / scale.y, 1 / scale.z));
    }

    void Draw(RenderState state) {
        mat4 M, Minv;
        SetModelingTransform(M, Minv);
        state.M = M;
        state.Minv = Minv;
        state.MVP = state.M * state.V * state.P;
        state.material = material;
        state.texture = texture;
        shader->Bind(state);
        geometry->Draw();
    }

    virtual void Animate(float tstart, float tend) {
        //std::cout << "animate Object " << std::endl;
        //rotationAngle = 0.8f * tend; 
        //I tried a basic rotation as animation, it works properly for every object, but it's not possible to change based on what object I want to animate, hence why I wanted to do that in a derived class.
    }
};
```

And last but not least, the probably faulty derived class that sadly has to cast it's geometry variable to ParamSurface in order to access some of it's functions, but in the meantime sadly casting the geometry variable of other instances that were members of the parent class, not the derived class as well.

```
struct ParamObject : public Object {

    ParamObject(Shader* _shader, Material* _material, Texture* _texture, Geometry* _geometry) : Object(_shader, _material, _texture, _geometry) {}

    //Animation for the Param Object
    void Animate(float tstart, float tend) {
            ParamSurface* ps = (ParamSurface*)geometry;
            ps->create();
            ps->Draw();
            //std::cout << "animate ParamObject " << std::endl;
    }
};
```

My questions are: 
1: Am I right to assume, that the derived object (ParamObject) class is the one causing my issues? (if I try to create every object as part of the parent class, they work, theyre just not animated/don't update even if their geometry would be changeing.)
2: In case I'm right, how do I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance: Wort

Comment: Remove the C-style casts and use C++ casts.  Then if there are compiler errors, read the error carefully.  Using C-style casts covers up potential errors.

Comment: so I tweaked the code a little bit, changed the C-style casts to C++ style ones as you suggested, but the results didn't change.
After that, I added a virtual function to the Geometry class, so I could simply reference that in the Object class's animate function, rather than having to use a derived class  for it, to get around the entire issue of casting said geometry variables. But as I found out, the create() and draw() functions for some reason use the last added geometry from the vertex array object buffer, rather than their own.
So basicly, as it turns out, casting it wasn't the issue.

Comment: The issue is fixed, I can't believe I forgot that I used copy constructors for the geometrys when I used them for objects, and they were only shallow copies, because I had no copy-constructor in them. @PaulMcKenzie , thank you for the help, even if the problem you pointed out wasnt the one that was causing the issue at hand.